# Determine if a function is a gamma distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Focusing on the last 2 equations...

[image]

Why is $$\frac{\lambda^{n+a-1} \exp\{ -\lambda(\sum x_i + b) \}}{\color{red}{(\frac{1}{\sum x_i + b})^{n+a}} \Gamma(n+a)}$$

I am thinking the part marked red doesnt belong to the PDF of a gamma distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does. Remember that $\lambda$ is the random variable here. If $Y$ follows a Gamma($\alpha, \beta$) distribution it has pdf
$$
f(y)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta y}.
$$

Replace $y$ with $\lambda$, $\beta$ with $\sum x_i+b$ and $\alpha$ with $n+a$ and you get:
$$
f(\lambda|x; a,b)=\frac{(\sum x_i+b)^{n+a}}{\Gamma(n+a)}\lambda^{n+a-1}e^{-\lambda(\sum x_i+b)}
$$
which is what you have (only written in a slightly different way). This then means that $\lambda\sim \text{Gamma}(n+a, \sum x_i+b)$.